# XML sing URI Reference only alphanumeric

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, signing

When I digitally sign an XML file with RSA it works perfectly, as long as the Reference URI is not numbers, and I need to sign the XML portion with a purely numeric ID.

I have 2 weeks of research and I can't find the way around.

This work perfectly

```
<book id="abc123">
    <title>Programming .NET Security</title>
    <author>Adam Freeman</author>
    <author>Allen Jones</author>
</book>


reference = New Reference
reference.Uri = "#abc123"
```

This does not work, malformed reference element

```
<book id="12345">
    <title>Programming .NET Security</title>
    <author>Adam Freeman</author>
    <author>Allen Jones</author>
</book>


reference = New Reference
reference.Uri = "#12345"
```

When the URI Reference is only numbers it doesn't work for me, if it has letters it works, I've tried it in C# and in VB.Net

Framework 3 to 4

Windows 10
Windows 2012 Server
Windows 2008

Comment: If you're trying to sign the entire file, then you should be setting `Reference.Uri` to an empty string. See the Remarks section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.reference.uri?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0. Not sure why an all-numeric URI doesn't work. I didn't see anything in the standards doc to indicate that it's not allowed.

Comment: Hi, I only want to sign one part, that's why I'm wanting to use Reference URI = 12345